# Python TCP socket doesn't close?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Maybe someone here will have a response for this thing which is just driving me insane.

To make it simple, I'm making a kind of proxy. Whenever it receives something, it forwards everything to a server, and sends back the response. So there is one socket always listening on port 4557 for clients, and for each incoming connection, there is a new socket created on a random port to connect to the server port 4556.

Clients <==> Proxy <==> Server

Also, there another socket which is instantiated and listening for requests coming from the server and to be forwarded to the corresponding client.

Here is an example:

- Client A connects to proxy on port 4557
- Proxy creates a socket to Server on port 4556
- Along with that, it creates a socket listening on port 40100
- Client sends stuff, forwarded to Server
- Client disconnects. Close client connection and socket to server
- Some time later, Server sends stuff to proxy on port 40100
- Everything's forwarded to Client A (port 40100 corresponding to Client A)
- And so on..

So far in my tests, I use a simple python script for sending a unique tcp packet to the proxy, along with a dump server showing received data and echoing back.

**So the issue is** that when a connection to the proxy is closed, the connection to the Server should also be closed with "sock.close()". However it just seems to be completely ignored. The socket remains as ESTABLISHED.

**About the code now.**

A few notes.

- DTN and Node are respectively Server and Clients.
- runCallback is called in a loop until thread dies.
- finalCallback is called when the thread is dying.
- Associations between remote hosts (Client), proxy ports (to Server) and proxies are kept in the dictionaries: TCPProxyHostRegister (RemoteHost => Proxy), TCPProxyPortRegister (Port => Proxy), TCPPortToHost (Port => RemoteHost).

The first class is TCPListenerThread.
It just listen on a specific port and instantiate proxies (one for each Client=>Server couple and Server=>Client couple) and forward them connections.

```
class TCPListenerThread(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, tcp_port):
        StoppableThread.__init__(self)

        self.tcp_port = tcp_port

        self.sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                        socket.SOCK_STREAM ) # tcp
        self.sock.bind( (LOCAL_ADDRESS, self.tcp_port) )

        self.sock.listen(1)

    def runCallback(self):
        print "Listen on "+str(self.tcp_port)+".."
        conn, addr = self.sock.accept()

        if isFromDTN(addr):
            tcpProxy = getProxyFromPort(tcp_port)
            if not tcpProxy:
                tcpProxy = TCPProxy(host, True)
        else:
            host = addr[0]
            tcpProxy = getProxyFromHost(host)
            if not tcpProxy:
                tcpProxy = TCPProxy(host, False)

        tcpProxy.handle(conn)

    def finalCallback(self):
        self.sock.close()
```

Now comes the TCP Proxy:
It associates a remote host (Client) with a port connecting to Server.
If it's a connection coming from a new Client, it will create a new listener (see above) for the Server and create a socket ready to forward everything to Server.

```
class TCPProxy():
    def __init__(self, remote, isFromDTN):
        #remote = port for Server or Remote host for Client
        self.isFromDTN = isFromDTN
        self.conn = None

        #add itself to proxy registries

        #If listening from a node
        if not isFromDTN:
            #Set node remote host
            self.remoteHost = remote
            TCPProxyHostRegister[self.remoteHost] = self

            #Set port to DTN interface + listener
            self.portToDTN = getNewTCPPort()
            TCPPortToHost[self.portToDTN] = self.remoteHost
            newTCPListenerThread(self.portToDTN)
        #Or from DTN
        else:
            self.portToDTN = remote
            TCPProxyPortRegister[self.portToDTN] = self

            self.remoteHost = getRemoteHostFromPortTCP(self.portToDTN)

    def handle(self, conn):
        print "New connection!"

        #shouldn't happen, but eh
        if self.conn != None:
            self.closeConnections()

        self.conn = conn

        #init socket with remote
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        if self.isFromDTN:
            self.sock.connect((self.remoteHost, 4556)) #TODO: handle dynamic port..
        else:
            self.sock.connect((DTN_Address, DTN_TCPPort))

        #handle connection in a thread
        self.handlerThread = newTCPHandlerThread(self)
        #handle reply in a therad
        self.replyThread = newTCPReplyThread(self)

    def closeConnections(self):
        try:
            if self.conn != None:
                print "Close connections!"
                self.sock.close()
                self.conn.close()
                self.conn = None
                self.handlerThread.kill()
                self.replyThread.kill()
        except Exception, err:
            print str(err)
            #pass

    def forward(self, data):
        print "TCP forwarding data: "+data
        self.sock.send(data)

    def forwardBack(self, data):
        print "TCP forwarding data back: "+data
        self.conn.send(data)
```

In this proxy class, I instantiate two classes, TCPHandlerThread and TCPReplyThread. They are responsible for forwarding to Server, and forwarding back to Client, respectively.

```
class TCPHandlerThread(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, proxy):
        StoppableThread.__init__(self)
        self.proxy = proxy

    def runCallback(self):
        test = False
        while 1:

            data = self.proxy.conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)    
            if test:
                self.proxy.sock.close()

            test = True
            if not data:
                break
            print "TCP received data:", data
            self.proxy.forward(data)
        self.kill()

    def finalCallback(self):
        self.proxy.closeConnections()



class TCPReplyThread(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, proxy):
        StoppableThread.__init__(self)
        self.proxy = proxy

    def runCallback(self):
        while 1:
            data = self.proxy.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not data:            
                break
            print "TCP received back data: "+data
            self.proxy.forwardBack(data)
        self.kill()

    def finalCallback(self):
        self.proxy.closeConnections()
```

You see that whenever a connection is closed, the thread dies and the other connection (Client/Server to proxy or Proxy to Server/Client) should be closed in Proxy.closeConnections()

I noticed that when closeConnections() is "data = self.proxy.conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)", it goes well, but when it's called even right after the latter statement, it goes wrong.

I wiresharked TCP, and the proxy doesn't send any "bye signal". The socket state doesn't go to TIME_WAIT or whatever, it just remains ESTABLISHED.

Also, I tested it on Windows and Ubuntu.

- On Windows it goes exactly as I explained
- On Ubuntu, it works well for usually (not always), 2 connections, and the third time I connect with the same client in exactly the same way to the proxy, it goes wrong again exactly as explained.

Here are the three files i'm using so that you can have a look at the whole code. I'm sorry the proxy file might not be really easy to read. Was SUPPOSED to be a quick dev.

http://hognerud.net/stackoverflow/

Thanks in advance..
It's surely something stupid. Please don't hit me too hard when you see it :(

Comment: Could you share where you are tracking the list of open client sockets, and how they are associated with a proxy socket to the proxied service?  I could spend some time reading the code, but this kind of basic info would make it easier so everyone isn't doing the same research.

Comment: Why do you post code that supposedly works and not code that doesn't, that which handles opening and closing the problematic server socket?

Comment: Thanks for comments. Initial post edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I'm sorry that I currently have not the time to actually run and test your code.

But the idea came to my mind, that your problem might actually have something todo with using blocking mode vs. non-blocking mode on the socket. In that case you should checkout the "socket" module help in the python documentation, especially socket.setblocking().

My guess is, that the proxy.conn.recv() function only returns, when actually BUFFER_SIZE bytes where received by the socket. Because of this the thread is blocked until enough data was received and therefore the socket doesn't get closed.

As I said first, this is currently just a guess, so please don't vote me down if it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Actually this solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: np - I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: Your guess is not correct. `recv()` returns when there is EOS, an error, or at least one byte has been transferred. Otherwise writing any kind of network code would be practically impossible.